# rendering page breaks in word with html

Tags: php, html, css, ms-word

I am generating documents with php in word and pdf format

I am using headers to generate a document in word

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=example.doc");
echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>"; etc etc
```

The wysiwyg is creating the following code to render pagebreaks

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

This html/css is working fine for the pdf output but not the word.

Can someone recommend an alternative method to create page breaks that may work in word.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379351/new-line-formatting-when-using-html-file-as-word-file

Comment: Issue is page breaks not line breaks

Comment: Have you tried outputting a FormFeed character (&#12;)?

Answer (score 31):

The question was asked a while ago but I'm adding this for reference:

I had the same issue and was able to make a page-break with this code

```
<br style="page-break-before: always">
```

The only way I could get it to work was with the "br" element and style it inline.

Comment: Words great for Word 2007. This should be the answer, IMO.

Comment: Works ok in Word 2016. Thank you for this solution!

Comment: It's important to mention that the result is only visible if you SAVE the page as html and then open in Word, if you try Copy -> Paste it won't work (tested with Word 2016)

Comment: I needed to add this in a `<pre>` tag to make it work. This is the only solution that doesn't give an extra line feed after the page break. Thanksss

Answer (score 4):

Inserting either of the following (where you want a page break) will work with MS Word 2000-2007 (and possibly with later versions):

`1) <br clear=all style='page-break-before:always'>`

`2) &#12; /* Ctrl-L = FF */`

Comment: Mine only worked with both together.. Word 2015. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
<pre><br clear=all style='mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always'></pre>
```

This is working for me to break content into next page.

Answer (score 2):

You will be scratching your head to figure out how Microsoft plays with the **standards** to force their own standards.

Try making a Word document with a page break - i.e. two pages. Save it as HTML and check the generated code for what style + tag combination is working for them.

Be aware that Word 2000 styling might be different from Word 2003 - which might be different from Word 2007 again - which might be different from Word 2010 again.

So adjust the solution based on which version of Word you are using because such differences are always there in Microsoft products. One similar issue is: Outlook 2003 uses the Internet Explorer engine to render HTML emails, while Outlook 2007 uses the Word rendering engine. HTML email showing with correct styles and fonts in Outlook 2003 will not show properly in Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer in case it's any use. None of the above worked for me in Word 365, but the following did:

```
<p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>
```